# Unable to import project in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to import https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview project in Android Studio, but I am getting following resolver error when I select 'Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)' :

> No such property: mavenDeployer for class:
>   org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

and

> The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.

when I select 'Use Local gradle distribution'
Gradle Home: ....../gradle-1.10

Answer (score 1):

Well, like it states, the version of Gradle is too low. Just use the latest Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Android Studio and also gradle version and after then import. Because your android studio have old gradle file configuration not match.
Second Option you can remove .idle folder inside your import project and try again it's work.